# rdelim braces in table misaligned due to setstretch

Tags: tables, bigdelim

Maybe someone can help me with this problem:

I have a simple table where I put some braces at the right side. This works good, but the braces are crossing/overlapping each other which doesnt look good (first picture). I figured out that when I dont use `\setstretch{1.433}` it looks good (second picture).

How can I avoid the braces to overlap when using setstretch?

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}   
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm,bm}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}

\addtokomafont{caption}{\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\Large}
\setkomafont{section}{\large}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\large\normalfont}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setstretch{1.433}  %commenting it out, it looks good

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}

    \begin{tabular}{c|c|l}
        \toprule
        Index & Test\\
        \midrule
        1 & 1&\rdelim\}{2}{*}[2]\\
        2 & 1&\\
        3 & 1&\rdelim\}{2}{*}[2]\\
        4 & 1&\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those rows before the ultimate row, the addition of `&&\\[-16pt]` is sufficient for introducing a gap.  For the final row, it unfortunately extends the vertical lines too far.  So there, I added a `\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}` as the last column of the last row.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}   
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm,bm}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}

\addtokomafont{caption}{\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\Large}
\setkomafont{section}{\large}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\large\normalfont}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setstretch{1.433}  %commenting it out, it looks good

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}

    \begin{tabular}{c|c|l}
        \toprule
        Index & Test\\
        \midrule
        &&\\[-16pt]
        1 & 1&\rdelim\}{2}{*}[2]\\
        2 & 1&\\
        &&\\[-16pt]
        3 & 1&\rdelim\}{2}{*}[2]\\
        4 & 1&\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, one could just use zero-width `\rule`s everywhere to essentially achieve the same result:

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|l}
    \toprule
    Index & Test\\
    \midrule
    1 & 1&\rdelim\}{2}{*}[2]\rule{0pt}{18pt}\\
    2 & 1&\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}\\

    3 & 1&\rdelim\}{2}{*}[2]\\
    4 & 1&\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```